# How to find common pair/group from multiple data frame

Tags: python, r, grouping

I have few data frame like this

```
DF1       DF2      DF3      DF4

A  1     A  2      A  1     A  1
B  2     B  2      B  2     B  2
C  3     C  3      C  4     C  3
D  2     D  4      D  3     D  4
E  4     E  1      E  2     E  3
F  2     F  2      F  2     F  2
G  3     G  1      G  4     G  3
```

Here, Number indicates group (Letters who have the same number are in the same group). Like in DF1, (B, D, F) have 2, so they are in the same group.

I want to figure out which group are available in all dataframe (like (B, F) are in the same group in all the dataframe. Again, (C, G) are in the same group for 2 dataframe.
So, I want to get which group (it can be more than 2 members) are available in all the dataframe and if they are not available at all the time, how many times they are in the same group. R and Python code is preferable.

Comment: What code have you tried? Seems to me a combination of `setdiff`, `lapply`/`%in%`, perhaps even `table` should be able to give you something usable.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, the total column lists the number of times a particular letter shows up in a data frame.

```
df <- data.frame(grp = LETTERS[1:7], 
                 df1 = c(1,2,3,2,4,2,3), 
                 df2 = c(2,2,3,4,1,2,1), 
                 df3 = c(1,2,4,3,2,2,4), 
                 df4 = c(1,2,3,4,3,2,3))

# Create a new column which counts the maximum number of times the letter
# has the same group in each dataset.

df$total <- apply(df[, 2:ncol(df)], 1, function(row) max(table(row)))

  grp df1 df2 df3 df4 total
1   A   1   2   1   1     3
2   B   2   2   2   2     4
3   C   3   3   4   3     3
4   D   2   4   3   4     2
5   E   4   1   2   3     1
6   F   2   2   2   2     4
7   G   3   1   4   3     2

# Show the rows for which the letters are present in the same group 
# across all datasets. 

df[df$total == ncol(df)-2,]

  grp df1 df2 df3 df4 total
2   B   2   2   2   2     4
6   F   2   2   2   2     4
```